# Extract extent (to class extent) of feature of spatial polygons data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a spatial polygons data frame and I would like to exact the extent of each feature (individual polygon) for use in a `crop()` function. I have tried

```
extent(spdf@polygons[1])
```

in an attempt to get the extent of polygon and that gives the error

> Error: c("x", "y") %in% names(x) are not all TRUE"

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: I don't find the function `extent`. Try : `bbox(spdf[1,])` with a loop on each polygon if necessary

Comment: extenet() is in the raster package. What you have here works though. extenet(bbox(spdf[1,])) gives me what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The means that I have used to do what I think you are asking for involves two packages, `rgdal` and `raster`

The code looks something like this:

```
require(rgdal)
require(raster)

newExtent <- extent(bbox(yourSpatialObject))
```

This defines the boundaries (bbox) and then generates an extent(). It should do what you need. You may have to work through your layers and objects one at a time or build a function to deal with many objects...but this should get you going

Answer (score 4):

You can subset the SpatialPolygons and then use the `raster::extent` method.

Example data:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
```

Now use a loop:

```
e <- list()
for (i in 1:length(p)) {
    e[[i]] <- extent(p[i,])
}
```

Or lapply:

```
e <- lapply(1:length(p), function(i) extent(p[i,]))
```

Or perhaps create a matrix:

```
e <- t(sapply(1:length(p), function(i) as.vector(extent(p[i,]))))
```